# CSS doesn't apply to the tag, write() method contains inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's Say I wrote a function that writes some text inside two different HTML tags and writes on to the page, onClick of a button. 
The problem is that the CSS styles are not getting applied to those tags...But when I put the relevant code ***outside the function*** it works fine.

My **JS code**,

```
let i;
function myFunction() {
            for (i=0; i<10; i++){
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    write_this = "<green>This</green>"
                }
                else {
                    write_this ="<red>That</red>"
                }
                document.write(write_this)
            }

}
```

**CSS code**

```
green {
    color: green;
}

red {
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="My Button">
```

onClick of the button, hopefully it does the job right...but those CSS colors are not getting applied to the relevant text

1. Why it doesn't work?
2. How to achieve what I want?

Comment: [Don't use `document.write()` it will rewrite the whole document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) if it was closed, including styles that have been added to the page. And since you are doing it onclick of a button the document will likely have been closed already

Comment: Use green and red this way `<span class="green">This is green text</span>` and add a dot in the style colors like `.green { color: green; }` and declare your variable in the function like `var write_this;`

Comment: You said, "CSS styles are not getting applied to those tags..."  that is because the document.write() wipes everything including the CSS styles you want to use to apply color for the green and red tags. @G-Cyr's answer shows a good example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @bron it doesn't work cause it doesn't fix the overwriting problem...should use innerHTML to address this..

Comment: The overwrite was already mentioned by Patrick. The syling was the orhter part of the problem.

Comment: @bron Just a clarification...is it because it's a good practice that I should use class instead of a tag to style...because even using <green> as a tag works fine

Comment: What framework or program do you use because `<green>` is **not** allowed in html code. See all allowed tags on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/

Comment: @bron I don't use any framework & I get it now...It's an illegal tag although it'll continue to work because it somehow will get added to DOM with minimal styling as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213028/html-illegal-tags-does-not-error-out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use innerHTML instead write to avoid erasing the whole document first.

about `write()`

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write
>
> Note: as `document.write` writes to the document stream, calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open`, **[which will clear the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes)**.

about `innerHTML`

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
>
> The Element property `innerHTML` gets or sets the `HTML` or `XML` markup contained within the element.

What you might try to do is more like :

```js
let i;

function myFunction() {
  var write_this = "";// prepare your var to update on the loop
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      write_this = write_this + "<green>This</green>"
    } else {
      write_this = write_this + "<red>That</red>"
    }
    
    // you may use a container
    document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = write_this;
  }

}
```

```css
green {
    color: green;
}

red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="My Button">
<p id="mybox"></p>
```

Comment: Ok cool, now I get it :) ....This only overwrites the elements inside p with the relevant Id. Thnx 
Bt just a clarification....Since write() is inside the for loop why it's necessary to keep updating write_this variable (write_this = write_this + "something")...If I'm not mistaken, each iteration is supposed to write, what the variable(write_this) holds at that iteration..
This is why the answer from @Shahar_Meshulam's answer doesn't work
Thnx

Comment: srry...I was so ignorant...In every iteration it overwrites what is in the p tag

Answer (score 1):

When your function do document.write(write_this) -> it is actually replace the current document with new content

so your previous html including your styles are deleted from the document...

change to:

```
function myFunction() {
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          write_this = "<green>This</green>"
        }
        else {
          write_this = "<red>That</red>"
        }
        document.body.innerHTML = write_this; // <------------
      }
```

Comment: This only writes what variable (write_this) holds at the last iteration (In this case <red>That</red>)
Declaring the write_this variable in the function & updating it with concatenation(write_this = write_this + "<green>This</green>") fixes that (I'm confused about this though..why it happens)...Thnk u